# Need help on using clearTimeout(); and setTimeout); Can't find solution

Tags: jquery, settimeout, fadein, fadeout, mousemove

I need a div(#thumbnails) to show and hide when the mouse hovers on div(#sliderBox). For that I used the hoverIntent plugin and worked like a charm.

I also want the div(#thumbnails) to fadeOut when idle for 5 secs. I managed to make it work using setTimeout();

**My problem is:** If I stay idle on top of the #sliderBox div the #thumbnails div won't fadeIn when I move the mouse again. I have to get my mouse cursor out of the #sliderBox div and hover back on it again to make the #thumbnails div fadeIn again.

Is there any way to fix this?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#thumbnails").hide();

$("#sliderBox").hoverIntent(showThumbs, hideThumbs);

  var timer;

  $(document).mousemove(function() {

        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = 0;
        }

        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $('#thumbnails').fadeOut(1000)
            }, 5000)
   });


 });

    function showThumbs(){ $("#thumbnails").fadeIn(1000);}
    function hideThumbs(){ $("#thumbnails").fadeOut(800);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with the plugin, which fires on `mouseenter`, so will not fire until you leave and enter again. The only solution is to modify the plugin itself, to trigger on `mouseenter` or `mousemove` (only after delay). The plugin looks pretty simple, and well commented. I don't think it will be too hard to modify.

Good luck and godspeed!

Comment: Your idea makes a lot of sense to me. But I'm having trouble making it work. I'm kinda new to Jquery. Coud you give me some advice?

Comment: You should look at the plugin code, and try to understand how it is working. It is short, well written and commented. Next, you should plan what you are going to try to achieve. Specifically around the modified logic - so you will need to keep track of the current state via a variable (is the box active, fading out, fading in, or faded out for example). Try to design the idea of where you will track this state change, and how you will respond to events differently. Try to think of it broadly, don't get caught up in the details of programming. Then ask specific questions here as they come up.

Comment: I did end up using states. I made a simple solution and added another variable to add a new state. That state defines if the thumbnails faded DUE to the timer. So basically if you move the mouse and such state is on it will invoke the onMouseEnter function and the thumbnails will fade in again. 

This is how the plugin looks now and works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Eblan85/tTjZv/

Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without needing to edit the plugin.

In addition to handling document's 'mousemove', handle sliderBox's 'mousemove', independent of the plugin but invoking the same `showThumbs()` function.

The code will be something like this (untested):

```
$(function(){
    var timer, $thumbnails = $("#thumbnails").hide();
    function showThumbs(){
        if($thumbnails.is(":hidden")){
            $thumbnails.fadeIn(1000);
        }
    }
    function hideThumbs(){ $thumbnails.fadeOut(800); }
    $("#sliderBox").on('mousemove', showThumbs).hoverIntent(showThumbs, hideThumbs);
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(hideThumbs, 5000);
    });
});
```

In `showThumbs()` you will see that I have made `$thumbnails.fadeIn(1000)` conditional. This is strictly unnecessary but gives `showThumbs()` less work to do, which is an important consideration now that it's attached as an 'onmousemove' handler.

Comment: Second thoughts, my suggested approach will probably negate the use of hoverIntent so jimmying the pluging is probably better.

Comment: And having said that, I'm not sure you don't run into the same problem by handling 'onmousemove' inside hoverIntent. Needs testing.